# Show that X is connected if and only if: $\forall O_1,O_2 \in \tau: X=O_1\cup O_2 \land O_1\cap O_2=∅ \Rightarrow O_1=∅ \lor O_2=∅$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let X be a nonempty set with topology $\tau$.
Show that X is connected if and only if the following implication holds:
$\forall O_1,O_2 \in \tau: X=O_1\cup O_2 \land O_1\cap O_2=∅ \Rightarrow O_1=∅ \lor O_2=∅$.

I have found this equivalent definition several times now when I needed to check the "contiguous" property for another task. But there was never a proof for it, so I wanted to ask here, how this looks like then.

For the "->" you have to check all the properties that are given, but there I get stuck all the time.
For the back direction, you could probably use contraposition (as an idea).

The only definition I knew for "contiguous" was: The only subsets of X which are both open and closed (clopen sets) are X and the empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your definition of connectedness if $X=O_1\cup O_2$ and $O_1\cap O_2=∅$ with $O_1,O_2 \in \tau$ then $O_1=X\setminus O_2$ so $O_1$ is closed.  Since it is closed and open it must be either empty or equal to $X$. The same is true of $O_2$.  But if both of these are equal to $X$ they won't be disjoint. So at least one one them is empty.

Converse:

It is given that $\forall O_1,O_2 \in \tau: X=O_1\cup O_2 \land O_1\cap O_2=∅ \Rightarrow O_1=∅ \lor O_2=∅$.

We want to show that if $A$ is  a set which is open and closed then it is $\emptyset$ or $X$.

Suppose $A$ is open and closed.  We use our hypothesis with properly chosen $O_1$ and $O_2$.

Take $O_1=A$ and $O_2=X\setminus A$ . Can you finish?

Comment: Is A a subset of X or a element of the topology?

Comment: $A$ is a subset of $X$ which assumed to be open and closed. Since it is open it belongs to $\tau$, right?  @clementine1001

Comment: I'm afraid I kind of don't understand your backward direction idea. Do you want to show that A is then only the empty set or X itself? And why is O_1 = A, what sense does that make? And what would O_2 look like anyway, if I am not allowed to use the definition to contiguous (we want to show it).

Comment: @clementine1001 I have added some details.